# How to make react-native-reanimated-carousel work with ImageZoom (react-native-image-pan-zoom)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, first-responder, react-native-reanimated-v2

I want to have a carousel that each item is a zoomable image, the carousel should be all over the screen so I use Portal for that. To support zoom I use `ImageZoom` component from `react-native-image-pan-zoom`, and the carousel is from `react-native-reanimated-carousel`, in the following way:

```
      <Portal>
        <Carousel
          loop
          windowSize={1}
          width={SCREEN_WIDTH}
          height={SCREEN_HEIGHT}
          data={images}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: "black",
          }}
          defaultIndex={imageIndexToDisplay}
          onSnapToItem={handleImageChange}
          renderItem={({ item: { url, width, height } }) => (
            <ImageZoom
              cropWidth={SCREEN_WIDTH}
              cropHeight={SCREEN_HEIGHT}
              imageWidth={width}
              imageHeight={height}
              enableSwipeDown
              onSwipeDown={handleClose}
              onClick={handlePress}
              useNativeDriver
            >
              <Image
                imageSource={url}
                defaultImage={defaultImage}
                imageStyle={{ height, width }}
              />
            </ImageZoom>
          )}
        />
      </Portal>
```

What happens is that the `carousel` barely let me scroll left or right since it seems like the `ImageZoom` responds first to the scrolls. I tried to set `onStartShouldSetPanResponder={() => false}` on the `ImageView` which solves the `Carousel` scrolling but doesn't let me use the `ImageZoom` to zoom since it appears like the `Carousel` now responds first to gestures.

I would like to know if there is any way to make them both work together.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement this with copying the contents of this pull request to my code base https://github.com/intergalacticspacehighway/react-native-reanimated-zoom/pull/19 and then using it as such:

```
import Carousel from 'react-native-reanimated-carousel';
import {Zoom, createReanimatedCarouselZoomComponent} from './zoom';

const WrappedCarousel = createReanimatedCarouselZoomComponent(Carousel);
...
const renderItem = () => <Zoom><Image ... /></Zoom>;
...
```

However I experienced some crashes on iOS simulator, so I will have to test on real devices.